# Can I display search results of a MS Access 2010 database into a combo box (Vb 2008)

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I need to have my program be able to search each column on a database until it finds matches, then output those matches into a combo box. I have currently programmed a way of it searching one column (specifically the name of an animal) but I need to add the option of searching other columns and displaying multiple results in a combo box that the user can then choose to open with the program into Form 2, which I use to display the data.

Here is my current code that I am using, the first part is for searching by the animal name, the second part is for searching in the optional box which then needs to display the results into the combo box. I also have the issue where I cannot search in the optional box unless the name box has data in it, which defeats the purpose of the optional box. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
 Private Sub btnsear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsear.Click
    If (txtname.Text = "'") Then
        MsgBox("No information has been entered")
    Else
        Try
            Dim newsql As String
            newsql = "select * from Animals where AnimalName like " & "'%" & txtname.Text & "%'"
            'MsgBox("select * from Animals where AnimalName like " & "'" & txtname.Text & "'")
            'MsgBox(newsql)
            Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

            'Dim ds As NewDataTable
            Dim dt As New DataTable("Animals")
            'uses the 2010 compatible connection string
            con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\Kamran\Desktop\College\Computing Project\Animals.accdb" 'h:\Animals.accdb"
            con.Open()

            da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(newsql, con)
            da.Fill(dt)

            Form2.Show()

            'show name in unbound text box
            Form2.nametxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
            Form2.latintxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
            Form2.locationtxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
            Form2.heighttxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)
            Form2.weighttxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(5)
            Form2.diettxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(6)
            Form2.statustxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(7)
            Form2.lifetxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(8)
            Form2.breedtxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(9)
            Form2.lengthtxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(10)
            Form2.txtimage.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(11)

        Catch
            'MsgBox("Animal Not Found")
            'con.close()
        End Try
    End If


    If txtname.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Search")
    Else
        Try
            Dim newsql As String = "SELECT * FROM Animals WHERE AnimalName LIKE " & "'%" & txtname.Text & "%'"

            If txtopt.Text <> "" Then

                newsql &= " AND (AnimalName LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR LatinName LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR Location LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR AverageHeight LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR AverageWeight LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR DietaryNeeds LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR ConservationStatus LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR AverageLifeSpan LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR BreedingSeason LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR AverageLength LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%')"
            End If

            Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

            Dim dt As New DataTable("Animals")

            con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\Kamran\Desktop\College\Computing Project\Animals.accdb" 'h:\Animals.accdb"
            con.Open()

            da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(newsql, con)
            da.Fill(dt)
    Catch
            'MsgBox("Item Not Found")
            'con.close()
        End Try
    End If
```

Comment: Forget the code for a second.  It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  Please clarify the bit about searching other columns.

Comment: In my database, data about animals are stored each animal uses a row and the separate parts of information such as weight and height form the columns. The code I have created so far can search the 'Animal Name' column and display the correct result depending on the data input. I need the optional text box to be able to search the other columns and match the data, I then need the results to displayed in a combo box (or something else suitable) and the user to be able to select the relevant animal and view the full set of data. Any better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second text box also contains query data from the user append it to your sql statement just like you did for the first field:  AND Field2 like %User Value%